# Implement Gravatar in Drupal 7 using php - how to connect mail addresses to “$email” variable

Tags: 7, users, media

Gravatar has a description of its php implementation on the following page:

https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/php/

I'm trying to use this code to implement it in Drupal's user profiles and user pictures.

1st I have created a preprocess function to enable printing e-mail addresses in user-profile.tpl.php

```
<?php function THEMENAME_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables) {
$account = $variables['elements']['#account'];
foreach (element_children($variables['elements']) as $key) {
$variables['user_profile'][$key] = $variables['elements'][$key];
}
$variables['user_profile']['mail'] = $account->mail;
field_attach_preprocess('user', $account, $variables['elements'], $variables);
}
?>
```

2nd Added the code to user-profile.tpl.php

```
print render($user_profile['mail']);
```

This code works what it's supposed to do - it displays mail address in the user profile. Now I need to use that address to create gravatars in profiles and in user pictures later.

I have somehow tried to connect the tutorial on Gravatar's site and this code, but without success. Here is the code (I have tried at least 20 different combinations):

```
<?php
$email = "['user_profile']['mail']";
$default = "http://www.somewhere.com/homestar.jpg";
$size = 40;
function get_gravatar( $email, $s = 80, $d = 'mm', $r = 'g', $img = false, $atts = array() ) {
        $url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/';
        $url .= md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) );
        $url .= "?s=$s&d=$d&r=$r";
        if ( $img ) {
            $url = '<img src="' . $url . '"';
            foreach ( $atts as $key => $val )
                $url .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $val . '"';
            $url .= ' />';
        }
        return $url;
    }
?>
```

As far as I understand, the problem is in this row:

```
$email = "['user_profile']['mail']";
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the right expression to put between quotes in this row?

Of course, it would be easier to use Gravatar module, but it seems buggy and unmantained.

Additionally, this php implementation seems to be relatively easy, but I'm probably missing something trivial.

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding but would you not just want `$email = $user_profile['mail']`?

Comment: @Clive I suppose that is the correct syntax, but there is still no output. Did I miss something from Gravatar's implementation guidelines? They have listed this example.